# php mysql using database row names in an array instead of numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function which pulls an entire row into an array but what I would like to do is use the row titles of en,de,es,fr,it in the array like me examples at the bottom

```
function translateWord($word,$lang){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_translate WHERE en = '$word'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    print_r($row);
}
translateWord('hi','fr');
```

**response**

> 1 [1] => hi [2] => hallo [3] => hola [4] => bonjour [5] => ciao )

Needs to be

> 1 [en] => hi [de] => hallo [es] => hola [fr] => bonjour [it] => ciao )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);

[en] => hi [de] => hallo [es] => hola [fr] => bonjour [it] => ciao )
```

Comment: Ideally, he wouldn't use any of the `mysql_*` functions at all, seeing as they're deprecated, but good answer nevertheless.